# Different between Capsa, Big two and Daifugō

Tags: playing-cards, variants

Is there any rule difference between Capsa (Indonesia), Big two (USA) and Daifugō (Japan)?
Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia, [Cap Sa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsa_(disambiguation)) and [Big Two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_two#Rules) are the same game while [Daifugo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daifug%C5%8D) has slightly different rules. I could scrutinize those pages and try to summarize the differences here, but I think there's no point: based on [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_two#Variations) and my experience, there are so many variations of these games that you will likely never find two people who play by the same rules anyway. So while it helps to have a general idea of how this class of "[shedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_game#Shedding_games)" games works, if you're playing with someone new you'll have to review all your rules or learn all theirs regardless of which game you are nominally playing.